# Different Contour Integration $\oint \frac{4z^3+6}{z(z-1-i)^2}dz$ C consists of $|z|=3$ counterclockwise and $|z|=1$ clockwise

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

Not sure where to begin and was wondering if anyone could give me a hint. I believe I would be using Cauchy's Integral Formula but figure out how to "split" the function...

Thanks.

Comment: Have you learned the Residue theorem?

Comment: Not quiet there yet...

Comment: @FrankLu If I have $Res_{z=0}=3i$ and $Res_{z=1+i}=8+5i$, do I merely just add them together?

Comment: And then multiply $2\pi i$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the standard formula for contour integrals which is $\int_{\gamma} f(z) dz=\int_{a}^{b}f(\gamma(t))\gamma^{'}(t)dt $  or  i suggest you use the Cauchy Integral Formula

Comment: Just use the dollar signs to enclose the tex.

Comment: I did thanks! It's the 1st time i answer and it is from a phone so i hope you won't be so harsh !

Comment: @BeslikasThanos Not sure how t0 apply the Cauchy Integram Formula.. how do I know $z_0$?

Comment: $z_0$ will be the center of the circle in most cases. The problem with those excercises is to locate the right function f to apply the formula. For the first case you cannot use the Cauchy Integral Formula because you have 2 poles. In the second case you can apply cauchy integral formula for $z_0=0$